# Solving a Windows common login user profile security issue

Tags: windows-7, permissions, remote-desktop, uac

Our group has a number of Test Stands with PCs that are currently being accessed with a single group login.

It has been sent from on high that this is not the way to do things for security reasons and we all agree. However. Multiple team members from around the world log into these Test Stands and need to be able to access programs that have been run from what would be different user profiles if we were to no longer have a single common login.

Is there a way to have a common workspace such that when different users login, they will be able to see and interact with all running applications as if they were using a common login?

Applications that we run link to and monopolize hardware resources connected to the PC and it is time consuming to restart and reload settings every time a new user logs in. Even if the program did not monopolize the hardware many of these programs are resource intensive and require a large portion of each machine's RAM to run, so trying to run the application again when it is already running from multiple user accounts would quickly consume all system resources.

Simple Example: I open a chrome browser while logged into our pc. I then disconnect without logging out and another team member remotes in and should be able to see my open browser and be able to interact with it as if he were the one who opened it.

Any alternative process flows or solutions from someone who has gone through a similar transition would be appreciated.

This is not a request for how to give all users access to the ability to run a program, but it is the request for how to allow all users access to interact with running applications that have been started by other users and need to be interacted with as if the new user started and has control of the application.

Alternatively, is there a way to force a login verification from a second account in order to access a shared login machine? Such that if I log into the shared account, I am also forced to enter my personal login details?

Comment: If you "logout" Chrome would have been closed as part of the logoff process. Do you mean disconnect without logging out of a RDP session or perhaps locking a workstation without logging off?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cant. 
this is only possible using the same login